# trying to use YearFrac in sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to use wct.YearFrac Function in sql using dates 2020-01-14 and 2020-12-31 but its not producing the correct data. any help ? Its returning 1 which isnt supoosed to be

Comment: What is the `yearfrac()` function?  What database are you using?  What results do you expect?

Comment: I'm using yearfrac (date1,date2, [basis]) and i expect it to produce a fraction like answer but its returning zero

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and there is no `yearfrac()` function in standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, i was able to resolve it. I was passing the wrong parameter hence why the error persist.